# half of heap usage but a lot of ehcache misses

Tags: java, hibernate, garbage-collection, ehcache

We have application on java6/solaris with hibernate3/ehcache and observe strange heap usage pattern (xmx=xms=4G) - there are peaks from 1.5G go 2.5G, each per 5 sec approx, like: /|/|/|/|/|  But in the same time we observe cache misses after some days (so caches are warm) in ehcache (via logging from  org.hibernate.Interceptor#onPrepareStatement hook).

So, the question is - how can cache misses happen in ehcache if there is still 1.5G of free heap above the peaks? Are these some issues with ehcache SoftReference implementation?

GC options:

> -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
>   -XX:+UseParNewGC
>   -XX:ParallelGCThreads=10
>   -XX:SurvivorRatio=8
>   -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=50
>   -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=5
>   -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
>   -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
>   -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
>   -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
>   -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
>   -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
>
> -Xms4G
>   -Xmx4G
>   -Xmn1024m
>   -Xss512k
>   -XX:PermSize=128m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

echache.xml (most entities have relationships to each other and don't have a lot of fields):

```
<defaultCache 
        maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
        eternal="true" 
        overflowToDisk="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" 
        /> 
    <!-- Entities regions --> 
<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="1500000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="3000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="50" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="50000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="10" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="1000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="200000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="50" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="50" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="70000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="50" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="7000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="800000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="70000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="100000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<!-- Collections regions --> 

<cache name="<class>.<collection>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="1500000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>.<collection>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="200000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>.<collection>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="500000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

<cache name="<class>.<collection>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

    <cache name="<class>.<collection>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="800000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />     

 <cache name="<class>.<collection>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="70000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" /> 

 <cache name="<class>.<collection>" 
       maxElementsInMemory="100000" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" 
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

s

Comment: Can you post your ehcache configuration file (e.g. ehcache.xml)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you limited your Ehcache to a certain number of in memory entries (ehcache-core 2.4) or to a maximum number of bytes (ehcache-core 2.5) then it's normal that he'll evict older entries in order to add in the new ones (even if the older ones are not yet expired). Try allocating more to the max in-memory limits configs, or activate the overflow to disk options :

http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/configuration

Also, what are you using to measure how much memory your app is taking, and what kind of objects are taking what quantity of memory?

You can use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) installed locally to your app's machine, and use the nice class instrumentation to profile object types memory occupation.

Comment: yes, limited by a certain number of entities (I've attached ehcache.xml). Memory load (peaks) was observed from VisualVM, I'll check class instrumentation also, thanks

Comment: Well if you, let's say double the maxElementsInMemory, does your cache entries get evicted less often?

Comment: memory profiler in jvisualvm doesn't work with remote jvm (our case):
Memory sampling:
Not available. Remote applications are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Ehcache, as configured, will not care about the memory available. Also it doesn't use anything like SoftReference internally. I would monitor if elements are actually being evicted. If they are it is because you've reached that limit you set per cache.

If you expect Size based tunings, I'd use Ehcache 2.5. Also are you using QueryCaching ?

Comment: [doc says](http://ehcache.org/documentation/faq#i-see-log-messages-about-softreferences-what-are-these-about-and-how-do-i-stop-getting-the-messages): it uses SoftReference. QueryCache - good idea, thanks!

Comment: So you are using RMI replication ? Cause, as far as I know there is no usage of SoftReferences in Ehcache but for net.sf.ehcache.distribution.EventMessage#elementSoftReference (and more recently within net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.ObjectGraphWalker). It was more of a question with regards to QueryCache, as there is an open issue with 2.5's size-based tuning and QueryCache usages...

Comment: thanks, you are right, I checked the sources too and saw that ehcache uses plain map, not SoftReferences. We don't use QueryCache, so will continue profiling to find out why cache misses.